# product states on the tensor product *-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let A and B be two unital $C^∗$-algebras, and $x∈A⊗B$ (the algebraic tensor product $*$-algebra), different from $0$. Is there states $ω_x∈A^∗_+$ and $φ_x∈B^∗_+$ such that, for the product state $ω_x×φ_x$, $(ω_x×φ_x)(x^∗x)>0$? In other words, do the product states separate the points of the tensor product $A⊗B$?

Comment: The question is essentially answered in: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108254/reference-request-tensor-products-of-states-separate-the-points-of-tensor-produ

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Lets write
$$
0 \neq x = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i \otimes b_i,
$$
so that the $b_i$ are linearly independent. For the moment, fix a state $\varphi$ on $A$.  This gives rise to the so-called slice map
$$
 \eta_\varphi \colon A \otimes B \to B : a \otimes b \mapsto \varphi(a)b.
$$
For this $\varphi$, we get 
$$
\eta_\varphi(x) = \sum_{i=1}^n\varphi(a_i)b_i.
$$
Clearly, one can choose $\varphi$ so that $\eta_\varphi(x) \neq 0$, since otherwise, by the linear independence of the $b_i$, $\varphi(a_i) = 0$, for any state $\varphi$ on $A$ and $i \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\}$. That would imply that $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_n=0$ and therefore $x= 0$. Now, we may take a state $\psi$ on $B$ such that 
$$
\psi(\eta_{\varphi}(x)) > 0.
$$
But $\psi(\eta_{\varphi}(x)) = (\varphi \otimes \psi)(x)$.

Comment: The question is essentially answered in: 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108254/reference-request-tensor-products-of-states-separate-the-points-of-tensor-produ

Comment: That answer uses way more machinery (and it depends on looking a result in a book), while the above is a straightforward elementary argument, that doesn't use tensor norms nor representations. All it requires is the fact that states separate points.

Comment: The above is not answering that I asked.

Comment: Yes it does. It shows that product states separate points, which is exactly what you asked.

Comment: better to read the details of my question: $x\neq0$ implies $\omega\times\varphi(x^*x)>0$, this is usually meant for "separate points" in operator algebras. By the way, I asked for that and the answer didn't respond about that question.

Comment: Note that $x \neq 0$ if and only if $x^*x \neq 0$. So in my post you may replace $x$ by $x^*x$ if you want. So I don't see why my post doesn't answer your question.